# Apache Cordova Tool VS 2013 - Unable To Attach

Tags: debugging, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Unable to attach debugger "File not Found" using template for Apache Cordova in vs 2013.  Happening on both Win 8.1 64 machine and win 7 SP1 64 machine.

Project builds and runs correctly in both emulator and ripple but generates error "Unable To Attach. The system can not find the file specified." No further information is given - as in what file is not being found, which would have been nice.

Unlike the other solutions I have seen on web, installs on both machines ARE on a system drive. Latest updates are installed for node, git and android sdk.  Environment variables and path variables are correct on both machines.  Tried all api's 19 and above, uninstalling and reinstalling the tool multiple times, updating from command line.

Issue occurred after switching from visual studio 2013 Pro update 3 to community edition update 4 on both machines.

Have even tried uninstalling every piece of software having to do with android dev (Eclipse, Android Studio, Cordova, Phonegap, the tool) and reinstalling the Cordova Tool with all of the default options.  Still same error on both machines - currently just using chrome to debug.

Noticed that it seems to be a similar error(the adb.exe error) but without the file name, given when trying to debug on a phone that has less than 4.4.

Any suggestions? Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: To clarify, it was working fine before with Visual Studio 2013 Pro, Update 3 but is no longer working with Community Edition, Update 4? Did you uninstall Pro before installing Community?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Uninstalled Pro on both machines and rebooted prior to installing community edition. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm still investigating. I didn't repro it with a fresh Win7 32-bit machine, VS Community 2013, and Cordova CTP3. I'll try the install/uninstall of Pro Update 3 and see what happens.

Comment: no problem at all.  I'm still trying to troubleshoot from this end also. It has to be something i am missing.  Not sure if it makes a difference but noticed that in ripple the the highest user agent in ripple is reading android 4.1.1 using the nexus 7 target - would that cause a problem with adb.exe?

Comment: I don't believe ADB is involved for Ripple (but I could be wrong, that's a bit lower level than my focus). Are your VS and Windows both English?

Comment: One more update. I uninstalled the community edition again, and reinstall the community edition with no luck.  I uninstalled the community edition and then reinstalled the pro edition and it works now and the debugger is able to attach.  As another note when i updated the pro edition to 4 I had to run the command prompt uninstaller for the cordova tool in order to update the cordova tool to ctp 3.  I didn't need to go through this step previously so I am thinking that parts of the cordova tool ctp 2 may have still been on the machine causing the inability to attach the debugger.

Comment: I will attempt to test uninstalling the cordova tool ctp 2 via the command prompton the win 7 machine now and reinstall ctp 3 while leaving the community edition on the machine and will see if that is the cause or if the cause has to do with pro/community editions.

Comment: This is the procedure i followed this time with uninstalling the cordova tool: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014133

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with the Win 7 machine still. Tried reverting back to pro and the other steps I performed on win 8.1 machine but still unable to attach debugger. Been using vs since 1998 and this is the first time that it has given me such issues. Really wish it actually gave me an error message that I could actually do something with - it telling me that some file out of the hundreds of thousands of files on the system can't load is completely useless.  Thank you again for your time on this.

Comment: One last update. On the Win 8.1 64 machine was able to move it back to the Community Edition by uninstalling pro and reinstalling community.  Everything still working on that machine - so looking like it is definately not related to Pro vs. Community.  Think more towards the update vrsion as when pro was first installed it had CTP 2 of the cordova tool.  Still no luck with WIn 7 64 machine though.  Will update if any progress

Comment: Same bug, Win 7 64bit + VS 2013 update 4. Project was updated from MDHA to Cordova Tools, and debugging now didn.t work. Tried to 'Repair' Cordova Tools, Chrome is up to date. Blank Cordova Tools project - same issue.

Comment: Are you running a localized version of Visual Studio? Even if you have the ENU language pack installed, if it was installed after the Cordova Tools, that could be the source of the problem. We are investigating this and it would be helpful to understand if it only occurs with localized versions of VS.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error and I successfully resolved it.

My configuration:

- Windows 7 Pro 64 bits - French
- Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 (French Edition)
- CTP 3

What I did to solve the problem:

- First, I installed ENU Language Pack for Visual Studio to install English language
- Then, I switched the language of my Visual Studio to english
- Finally, I repaired my CTP 3.0 installation.

After that, I was able to debug application from my android device.

Another solution (but not suitable for everyone since it's required a MSDN Account) : using the Visual Studio 2015 Preview.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version/build number/size of the resources assembly in

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.resources\12.0.* ?

You can right click on the binary and check its properties.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post questions in the answer section of a question. This post should be a comment. Once you have enough reputation, you can leave comments on questions, answers or other comments. Until then, please refrain from postings such as these.